# Как добавить объект сложного типа в поле таблицы SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Вот такого типа объекты мне нужно добавить в таблицу с СУБД SQLite:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public Ticket(Ticket ticket) : this(ticket.Number, ticket.Question, ticket.Answers)
    {

    }
    public Ticket(int number, string question, List<TicketAnswer> answers)
    {
        Number = number;
        Question = question;
        Answers = answers;
    }
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public string Question { get; private set; }
    public List<TicketAnswer> Answers { get; private set; }
}
```

*И этот тип содержит в себе ещё и коллекцию вида `List<TicketAnswer>`.*

Comment: Если ваш объект состоит из нескольких свойств и таких объектов у вас может быть несколько, то лучше сделать отдельную таблицу из которой вы программно потом будете брать все необходимое. Например "Билет" - отдельная таблица, каждый билет имеет свой Id. Дальше например таблица "Тест" - это тоже отдельная таблица, которая содержит в себе список всех тестов, где каждый тест имеет "Вопросы" - некий список Id вопросов (id из таблицы вопросов). Не стоит пихать все в одну кучу! Ну а если так хочется, то не знаю, сериализуйте ваш объект и добавляйте в "поле таблицы"...

Comment: ... либо выберите другую бд — нереляционную, например, что-то вроде LiteDb: https://www.litedb.org/